# DataRowCollection issue in datatable

Tags: c#, collections

What is the difference between `test.Rows[0]` and `test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1]` if rows is a collection in a datatable.For example
if count =o or count = -1 what will be the situation here

My intention was to determine the last value in that collection.If no value is there in that collection will it make problems
Previously test.Rows[0]["Level"] is always giving 18 digit number but when i made in to test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1]["version"] it is giving correct one

**SO finally my question is  if count = 1  will both statement test.Rows[0] and test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1] will be equal or what is the situation will both statement are equal**
I debugged code ,if i go with test.Rows[0]["Level"] it always showing one 18 digit constant value,why it is showing like that.This Test is a datatable in .xsd file where i can see one and only 'Level' row

Comment: What @marc explained is correct but right way to access rows is foreach loop instead of accessing it through numbers

Comment: @user751975 if you only want the first or last (or any other specific row), then `foreach` is ***not*** the correct approach. That is the correct approach only if you want to read *all* the rows (or enough of the rows that looping over them all is sensible).

Comment: Absolutely right @MArc then as suggested by you linq is there but using indexing to read rows is error prone

Comment: @user751975 *everything* is error-prone to some small degree; indexers are perfectly well defined...

Comment: My intention was to determine the last value in that collection.If no value is there in that collection will it make problems

Comment: Previously test.Rows[0]["Level"] is always giving 18 digit number but when i made in to test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1]["version"] it is giving correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a zero-based collection / array / list, etc; item `0` and item `count - 1` are the first and last items respectively.

> For example if count =o

If the collection does not *have* any items, either of the above will usually result in an out-of-range exception. So... don't do that. Check the size first.

> or count = -1

If the count is -1, you have bigger problems - like, you broke the universe

You might also look at LINQ's `FirstOrDefault()` / `LastOrDefault()` etc (both have special checking for typed lists to minimise pain - but I don't know if `.Rows` *is* technically a typed list (`IList<T>`) - I suspect not); but access via an indexer is convenient and fast.

Comment: My intention was to determine the last value in that collection.If no value is there in that collection will it make problems

Comment: @shanethomson11 - yes, it will; so decide first what you want your code to do when there are no rows... and write it accordingly

Comment: Previously test.Rows[0]["Level"] is always giving 18 digit number but when i made in to test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1]["version"] it is giving correct one

Comment: SO finally my question is  if count = 1  will both statement test.Rows[0] and test.Rows[test.Rows.Count - 1] will be equal

Comment: @shanethomson11 ... er, yes. `1 - 1 === 0`, so that is just `Rows[0]` twice.

Comment: I debugged code ,if i go with test.Rows[0]["Level"] it always showing one 18 digit constant value,why it is showing like that.This Test is a datatable in .xsd file where i can see one and only  'Level' row

Comment: Is there any default value for each rows in datatable

Comment: @shanethonson11 depends on the table